# Optimizing a slow Postgres Query that takes > 4 seconds to run

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Here is my Postgres Query:

```
select 
    date_trunc('month', member.member_since), 
    count(member_change.member_id)
from 
    member_change 
left join 
    member on (member_change.member_id = member.member_id)
left join
    import_stats on member_change.import_history_id = import_stats.import_id
where 
    member.account_id = 1050007 and 
    change_source = 'i' and 
    change_type = 'a' and 
    member_status_id = 'a' and 
    member_since >= '2015-08-01' and 
    member_change.import_history_id in (select import_id from import_stats where account_id = 1050007) 
group by 1;
```

Here is the explain analyze on the query

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=43.50..43.55 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=2.727..2.728 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=18.00..43.48 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=2.089..2.717 rows=33 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (public.member_change.import_history_id = public.import_stats.import_id)"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 79"
"        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=18.00..33.68 rows=4 width=24) (actual time=0.121..0.715 rows=33 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (public.import_stats.import_id = public.member_change.import_history_id)"
"              ->  Append  (cost=0.00..14.10 rows=411 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.584 rows=7 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on import_stats  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on import_stats  (cost=0.00..14.10 rows=410 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.583 rows=7 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=17.97..17.97 rows=2 width=24) (actual time=0.108..0.108 rows=33 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=15.72..17.97 rows=2 width=24) (actual time=0.077..0.098 rows=33 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (public.member.member_id = public.member_change.member_id)"
"                          ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2.08 rows=38 width=16) (actual time=0.024..0.038 rows=34 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on member  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((member_since >= '2015-08-01 00:00:00-05'::timestamp with time zone) AND (account_id = 1050007) AND ((member_status_id)::text = 'a'::text))"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on member  (cost=0.00..2.08 rows=37 width=16) (actual time=0.019..0.030 rows=34 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((member_since >= '2015-08-01 00:00:00-05'::timestamp with time zone) AND (account_id = 1050007) AND ((member_status_id)::text = 'a'::text))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 28"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=15.70..15.70 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.048..0.048 rows=61 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3kB"
"                                ->  Append  (cost=0.00..15.70 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.007..0.026 rows=61 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on member_change  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                            Filter: ((change_source = 'i'::text) AND (change_type = 'a'::text))"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on member_change  (cost=0.00..15.70 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.022 rows=61 loops=1)"
"                                            Filter: ((change_source = 'i'::text) AND (change_type = 'a'::text))"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 27"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..9.62 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.059..0.060 rows=3 loops=33)"
"              ->  Append  (cost=0.00..9.61 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=4 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on import_stats  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: (account_id = 1050007)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on import_stats  (cost=4.27..9.61 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=4 loops=1)"
"                          Recheck Cond: (account_id = 1050007)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_import_stats_account_id  (cost=0.00..4.27 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=4 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (account_id = 1050007)"
"Total runtime: 3.447 ms"
```

Basically I am just trying to get the aggregated count of members added where `change_source='i'`. The `member_change` table is pretty massive (upwards of well over a million records and counting) but I can't get the query to get under 1 second

Comment: Total runtime 3.4 milliseconds not seconds.

Comment: I need to get the output from the server (that runtime is misleading since it was from local data)

Comment: You are talking about data transfer time not query execution time. You can only reduce the data transfer time by reducing its size. Nothing done to the query will reduce it.

Comment: The query returns only **2** rows with a date and an integer column. That's 64 bytes in total plus some protocol overhead. If that really takes 4 seconds to send over the network, then you have a serious problem with the network or the way your application processes the two rows. There is absolutely nothing you can do in SQL to improve this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is one row for each month. But still very few rows.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: the explain output says it returned 2 rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, didn't notice that. But even if production data returns many months it is still very few rows.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I suspect Dennis is not showing us the query from production but from some test system.

Comment: Note: `left join member` + `member.account_id = 1050007 and ...` classic case IMHO